# DataFrame won't show me a table form when I iterate in a forloop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have a string, and I want to take every word in that string and then find the row that contain that token in a dataframe in the token column, like so:

```
for word in "hello there".split():
       print( pd.DataFrame(tokens.loc[tokens['tokens'] == word]))
```

but it prints something like this:

```
     tokens  egypt    gulf  hijazi  maghribi
32877    hello  611.0  1322.0   507.0     463.0
```

that's not a table form that dataframe prints. just a normal string. But when I remove that line from the for loop, it prints in a table form.

**Please notice:**
The above for loop is inside another for loop, there're many tables that I want print.

#### Some problems I found:

when I use print, it gives me this plain table form, but when I remove it, it shows me the dataframe table with gray background form. The problem is, I need a separate cell(using jupyter) to print it like that. But I need to do it inside a for loop because there're other tables I need to print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that tokens is a dataframe with the columns 'tokens' and 'values'. If you are looking to print only those rows where entries in the 'value' column match certain words in a string, you are better off using pandas internal matching logic via the .isin method.

So if tokens is a dataframe such as this:

```
tokens=pd.DataFrame({'tokens':['egypt','gulf','hijazi','maghribi','hello'],'values':[32877,611.0, 1322.0, 507.0, 463.0]})
```

You could simply write:

```
print(tokens[tokens['tokens'].isin("hello there".split())])
```

Comment: When I use print, it gives me string, not as table form. how to avoid this

Comment: if it is simply a formatting issue, just try using display(dataframe) rather than print(dataframe)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update it to a new df,

```
>>> new_tokens = pd.DataFrame(columns=tokens.columns)
>>> tokens
   tokens  egypt    gulf  hijazi  maghribi
0   hello  611.0  1322.0   507.0     463.0
1  helalo  611.0  1322.0   507.0     463.0 # For testing this line is added
>>> for word in "hello there".split():
       new_tokens = new_tokens.append(tokens.loc[tokens['tokens'] == word])


>>> new_tokens
  tokens  egypt    gulf  hijazi  maghribi
0  hello  611.0  1322.0   507.0     463.0
```

Comment: okay, I found the problem, when I use print(df), it prints as plain text. But when I only write df, it gives me the table form. But how to avoid this? I tried removing the print and it won't show anything. I mean removing it inside the for loop. there's actually a bigger loop as well, because there're other strings that I need to print

Comment: @JohnSall Data type of `df` is DataFrame. Where you want to display your dataframe as table? In which environment you are printing? Default IDLE or Jupyter or anything else? print(df) is not an issue. You can the type of `df`.

Comment: I'm using jupyter, but no, when I use print, it gives me plain text. I have to add another cell, and only write df there and it would show me the table form with gray background

Comment: df is just a variable here